# Estimating within group variability given high uncertainty

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, random-effects-model

Suppose we have products $P_i$ $(i=1,2,\cdots,N)$. Each product has three different descriptions, which we denote by $(X_{ij},y_{ij})$ for $j\in \{1,2,3\}$, where $X_{ij}$ are the description features, and $y_{ij}$ is the click-thru rate on the item, based on description $X_{ij}$. In the wild we estimate $y_{ij} = S_{ij}/T_{ij}$ where $S_{ij}$ is the successful click-thrus and $T_{ij}$ is the total number of impressions of the item. For the sake of this discussion, we can assume $y_{ij}$ are all near 0.1, so I'll commonly say "statistically significant" to be equivalent to large $T_{ij}$.

We want to build a model $M(X_{ij})$ that tries to predict $y_{ij}$. Inherently there are three fundamental issues:

1) $T_{ij}$ tends to be fairly small, implying that $y_{ij}$ has large variance.

2) So there are two forms of variance involved. The first is from smaller $T_{ij}$. The second is from the abstract space of all possible descriptions of item $P_i$. So very roughly speaking, if you pick a random description of $P_i$, it'll come from a distribution with some mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i$.

3) The description variance $\sigma_i$ seems to increase with larger $\mu_i$, as verified on items $P_i$ that have low uncertainty variance (large $T_{ij}$).

What exactly is the right approach toward training a model $M(X_{ij})$ in this setup? The use case for this is to predict click-thru rates for descriptions of a given product before manually testing them in the wild. So it's imperative that the model is able to distinguish between two different descriptions for the same product. But, just as well, I'd like to verify that the model is working correctly on a validation set. So this means figuring out if it can make predictions that are more accurate than just the uncertainty variance for each product. I feel like for validation, I would have to subset to products which have way more clicks, to ensure statistical significance?

I'm confident that I can predict $\mu_i$ reasonably well for all the products, but I'd be much more interested in being able to figure out which description is better for a particular item. This seems much more difficult given that a large portion of the variance is due to uncertainty. It feels like a random-effects model, except the variance of the random effects seems to vary given the effect size. Is the correct approach to try a link function that equalizes the variance?

The part I'm having trouble with is discerning whether the predicted click-thru rates within-products are statistically significant. In other words, is the model just predicting uncertainty variance (so it's outputs are just bigger by chance), or is it actually capturing the within-product variance?